# SQL Update table based on conditions in separate table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, where-clause, multiple-tables

I have two tables each containing thousands of records on security deposits that have been paid or are owed. The format is like this:

```
Table A
ID   ID2    ID3   Payment
1    REG    P     102.5
2    REG          120
3    REG    P     65.5

Table B
ID     Payment
1      17.5
2      0
3      45.5
```

Where Table A shows the amount that has already been paid and table B shows the amount that is still due. I would like to update table B so that any time a security deposit has not been fully paid off, I show the total amount charged. For example, for ID 1, I would like to update B.Payment to be equal to A.Payment+B.Payment but I don't want ID 2 to be updated because this deposit has already been paid in full. I tried using the following code but it updates every row in my table instead of just the rows with partial payments:

```
UPDATE B 
SET B.[Payment] = (A.[Payment] + B.[Payment]) 
FROM B LEFT JOIN A ON A.[ID] = B.[ID] 
WHERE A.[ID2] = 'REG' and A.[ID3] = 'P'
```

How do I only update fields in table B when conditions in table A are met?

Comment: Why you want do this? Unless you create a trigger to keep the table update you will be holding old data values. is better create a `View`

Comment: What is your RDBMS? different DB has different `UPDATE JOIN`  sintaxis

Comment: Juan Carlos - this is a single update, after this update is run, data will be added in the new format rather than the old format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE b SET b.Payment = b.Payment + a.Payment
FROM B b 
    JOIN (SELECT a.ID, Payment = sum(Payment) FROM A a 
          WHERE a.ID2 = 'REG' AND a.ID3 = 'P'
          GROUP BY a.ID) a ON b.ID = a.ID
```

It sums all payments in table A for each ID, then adds it to the Payment column in table B.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure on what b.id2 refers to in your code.

Try this

```
UPDATE b
SET b.payment = b.payment +
                (SELECT a.payment FROM a WHERE a.id=b.id AND a.id2='REG')
WHERE b.payment<>0;
```

Comment: I apologize that I was not clear - I just updated my original question to fix the issue with b.id2. I think that the code you suggested is close to what I need but the deciding factor for when the update should happen is actually when A.ID3 = 'P', not when B.payment <> 0. This is where I am struggling - since the updates in B depend on multiple columns in A.